# error while trying to predict on images in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a website that can make predictions on images using tensorflow, flask, and python.
This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')


import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_PATH)

IMG_SIZE = 224
BATCH_SIZE = 32

custom_path = "http://t1.gstatic.com/licensed-image?q=tbn:ANd9GcQd6lM4HtInRF3cxw6h3MgUZIIiJCdMgFvXKrhaJrbw61tN3aYpMIVBi0dx0KPv1sdCrLk0sBhPeNVt8m0"


custom_data = create_data_batches(custom_path, test_data=True)

custom_preds = model.predict(custom_data)


# Get custom image prediction labels
custom_pred_labels = [get_pred_label(custom_preds[i]) for i in range(len(custom_preds))]
print(custom_pred_labels)

@app.route('/my-link/')
def my_link():
  return f"The predictions are: {custom_pred_labels}"
  
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host="localhost", port=3000, debug=True)
```

**The process_image function:**

```
def process_image(image_path, img_size=IMG_SIZE):
  """
  Takes an image file path and turns the image into a Tensor.
  """
  image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, size=[img_size, img_size])

  return image
```

**The needed part of the create_data_batches function:**

```
def create_data_batches(X, y=None, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, valid_data=False, test_data=False):
  """
  Creates batches out of data out of image (X) and label (y) pairs.
  Shuffles the data if it's training data but doesn't shuffle if it's validation data.
  Also accepts test data as input (no labels)
  """
  if test_data:
    print("Creating test data batches...")
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(X))) # only filepaths (no labels)
    data_batch = data.map(process_image).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    return data_batch
```

**The get_image_label function:**

```
def get_image_label(image_path, label):
  """
  Takes an image file path name and the associated label, processes the image and returns a tuple of (image, label).
  """

  image = process_image(image_path)
  return image, label
```

**The get_pred_label function:**

```
def get_pred_label(prediction_probabilites):
  """
  Turns an array of prediction probabilities into a label.
  """
  return unique_breeds[np.argmax(prediction_probabilites)]
```

Now when I run this, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Unbatching a tensor is only supported for rank >= 1
```

I tried turning it into a list as one of the solutions I found said:

```
custom_path = ["http://t1.gstatic.com/licensed-image?q=tbn:ANd9GcQd6lM4HtInRF3cxw6h3MgUZIIiJCdMgFvXKrhaJrbw61tN3aYpMIVBi0dx0KPv1sdCrLk0sBhPeNVt8m0"]
```

But when I run that, I get this error:

```
UNIMPLEMENTED:  File system scheme 'http' not implemented (file: 'http://t1.gstatic.com/licensed-image?q=tbn:ANd9GcQd6lM4HtInRF3cxw6h3MgUZIIiJCdMgFvXKrhaJrbw61tN3aYpMIVBi0dx0KPv1sdCrLk0sBhPeNVt8m0')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your image into memory like this then feed that to tensor flow:

```
import urllib.request
def imageLoad(URL):
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.5 Safari/605.1.15'}
        req = urllib.request.Request(URL, headers=headers)
        with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as url:
            img = image.load_img(BytesIO(url.read())).resize((180, 180))
            img_array = np.array(img)
    
        return img_array
    
img = imageLoad(image_path)
```

Comment: Adjust your image size accordingly from resize((180, 180)) to 224